# save arrays in mysql with reactjs and php

Tags: php, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a form in reactjs which has a normal variable called "name" and two arrays, one called "data1" and the other "data2", but when saving from reactjs it is only saving the variable "name" in base of data.

I need that they also save the arrangements in the database but I have not achieved it.

the mysql database only has one table called revenue2 and 4 fields: revenue_id, name, data1, data2

https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-browser-nvcee?file=/src/App.js

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import {
  Grid,
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableContainer,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  Paper
} from "@material-ui/core";
import AddCircleOutlineIcon from "@material-ui/icons/AddCircleOutline";
import { withStyles, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";

const StyledTableRow = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "&:nth-of-type(odd)": {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.hover
    }
  }
}))(TableRow);

const options = [
  { value: 1, label: 1 },
  { value: 2, label: 2 },
  { value: 3, label: 3 }
];

function Pruebas() {
    const baseUrlAd = 'https://www.inventarios.gemcont.com/apiGemcont/compras/ingresos/'; 
    const [data, setData]=useState([]);
    const [frameworkSeleccionado, setFrameworkSeleccionado]=useState({
        id_ingreso:'',
        nombre:'',
        dato1:'',
        dato2:''
      });

    const handleChange=e=>{
        const {name, value}=e.target;
        setFrameworkSeleccionado((prevState)=>({
          ...prevState,
          [name]: value
        }))
       console.log(frameworkSeleccionado);
      }

      const peticionPost = async() =>{
        var f = new FormData();
        f.append("nombre", frameworkSeleccionado.nombre);

        f.append("dato1", frameworkSeleccionado.dato1);
        f.append("dato2", frameworkSeleccionado.dato2);
        f.append("METHOD", "POST_prueba");
        await axios.post(baseUrlAd,f)
        .then(response=>{
         setData(data.concat(response.data));
        }).catch(error=>{
          console.log(error);
        })
    
      }


  const [roomInputs, setRoomInputs] = useState([
    { dato1: "", dato2: "" }
  ]);

  
  const handleRoomChange = (value, index, name) => {
    const list = [...roomInputs ];
    list[index][name] = value;
    setRoomInputs(list);
  };

  const handleRemoveClickRoom = (index) => {
    const list = [...roomInputs];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setRoomInputs(list);
  };

  const handleAddClickRoom = () => {
    setRoomInputs([...roomInputs, { dato1: "", dato2: "" }]);
  };

  
 
    return (
<div className="content-wrapper">
    
    <div className="content-header">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        
          <div className="col-sm-12">

          <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
              <h3 class="card-title">Datos</h3>
              </div>
            
              <div class="card-body">
                
                  <div class="row">  

                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" name="nombre"
                  placeholder='nombre' className="form-control" onChange={handleChange}/>
                  </div>
                  </div>


                  </div>

                  <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                  
                  
        <br />
          <Grid item sm={12}>
            <TableContainer component={Paper} variant="outlined">
              <Table  aria-label="customized table">
                <TableHead>
                  <TableRow>
                    <TableCell>#</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="left">dato1</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="left">dato2</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                  
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                  {roomInputs.map((x, i) => (
                    <StyledTableRow key={i}>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                        {i + 1}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="left">
                        <input 
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        name="dato1"
                        value={options.value}
                        //onChange={option => handleRoomChange(option, i, "dato1")}
                        onChange={event => handleRoomChange(event.target.value, i, "dato1")}
                        />
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="left">
                      <input 
                        type="number"
                        name="dato2"
                        className="form-control"
                        value={options.value}
                        //onChange={option => handleRoomChange(option, i, "dato2")}
                        onChange={event => handleRoomChange(event.target.value, i, "dato2")}
                        />
                      </TableCell>

            

                      <TableCell align="left">
                        {roomInputs.length !== 1 && (
                          <DeleteIcon
                            onClick={() => handleRemoveClickRoom(i)}
                            style={{
                              marginRight: "10px",
                              marginTop: "4px",
                              cursor: "pointer"
                            }}
                          />
                        )}
                        {roomInputs.length - 1 === i && (
                          <AddCircleOutlineIcon
                            onClick={handleAddClickRoom}
                            style={{ marginTop: "4px", cursor: "pointer" }}
                          />
                        )}
                      </TableCell>
                    </StyledTableRow>
                  ))}
                </TableBody>
               
                  
              </Table>
            </TableContainer>
          </Grid>
         
      
     
             </div>
                  </div>
                  <br />
                  <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={()=>peticionPost()}> Registrar</button>
               
              </div>
             
            </div>     

      </div>

      </div>
      </div>
    
  </div>
    )
}


export default Pruebas
```

php

```js
<?php

include '../../bd/global.php';

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');


if($_POST['METHOD']=='POST_prueba'){
    unset($_POST['METHOD']);
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $dato1=$_POST['dato1'];
    $dato2=$_POST['dato2'];
    $query="insert into ingresos2(nombre,dato1,dato2) values ('$nombre','$dato1','$dato2')";
    $queryAutoIncrement="select MAX(id_ingreso) as id_ingreso from ingresos2";
    $resultado=metodoPost($query, $queryAutoIncrement);
    echo json_encode($resultado);
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    exit();
}


header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refactor `handleChangeRoom` as below

```js
const handleRoomChange = (value, index, name) => {
   
    setFrameworkSeleccionado((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value
    }));
   
  };
```

Demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-sara-or05xx?file=/src/App.js:2167-2326

Comment: it only saves me the first value of data1 and data2, but if I add more values ​​to data1 and data2 it does not save everything

Comment: I don't have a wide insight on what you wan to achieve, just use solution as reference

Comment: In my form in reactjs there are two arrays, one is called data1 and the other is called data2, and these arrays can contain several records as I show in my codesanbox, and with the solution you gave me, only the first two can be saved.